# How to convert axis from nanometer to angstrom in xmgrace?

Tags: axis, xmgrace

I have plotted the graph in which the x-axis values are in nanometer. But i want to the x-axis in angstroms.

How can i do this? From axis transform in Xmgrace?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? Do you want to just change the axis label or you want to also rescale your data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to rescale the values of your x data series by a multiplication factor. In your case, in order to convert nm to angstrom you would multiply the x data by 10, e.g. 0.1 nm would become 1 Angstrom.

In the xmgrace GUI menu click `Data > Transformations > Evaluate Expression`

**Method 1: Modifying the original set**

In both the "Source" and "Destination" panes select the same set you want to convert so it is highlighted.

In the Formula box type `X = X*10` then click Apply.

**Method 2: Creating a new set first**

On either the "Source" or "Destination" pane right-click on the existing set and `Duplicate` it.

Now select the original set on the left, and the new set on the right.

In the Formula box type `X = X*10` then click Apply.

You can now select either the original or transformed set and hide the other one.

**Finally...**

In both Methods, now you can set your x axis label to display the updated units.

Comment: Is there a way to pass axis transformation rules from the command line, for pipe purposes?